# How did the first off-world team know the return address for Atlantis?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

In the first episode of *Stargate Atlantis*, the Atlantis expedition group hastily sends a team through the stargate after discovering that the city seems to be in imminent danger of being flooded. Unless I missed it, the Pegasus galaxy address for Atlantis is never mentioned or given to this team prior to them going through the gate.

Even if everyone in the Atlantis expedition had memorized the Milky Way address for Atlantis, this would have been useless once *in* the Pegasus galaxy as the gates have different symbols. So how did this first off-world team know what address to dial to return to Atlantis?

Comment: Would it not be the same address as the one dialed from Earth, albeit without the 8th Chevron? If so, they would've had plenty of time to learn it whilst on Earth

Comment: @Robotnik No, the glyphs are completely different between the two galaxies

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As NominSim noted, they had access to the Atlantis database (which is where Rodney found the address of a planet to dial out to) when the team leaves, so presumably they were able to obtain the Pegasus address for Atlantis from there.

Additionally, as the team is preparing to leave we see Grodin running down the main stairs of the Atlantis gate room from the control area with a device in hand, presumably with the Pegasus address for Atlantis on it.  He is then seen conferring with Shepard and the departing team, so we can infer that he gave them the information at that point.

Given that Grodin was not military, the urgency of the situation, and the lack of a wraith threat at this point, it seems possible that he simply wrote down the address and handed it to them (though obviously even without a known threat writing down the address for a team leaving for an unknown destination was probably a bad idea).

Comment: Makes the most sense. I wish they'd at least briefly refer to this kind of thing, though. Writers: I don't require TV to spell everything out for me, but at least hang a latern on it when it otherwise looks like you forgot!

Answer (score 5):

They found the addresses for other gates withing the Atlantis database, so presumably they found the information from there. Being the pilot episode I think they left out the dialogue of "How do we know what address to use to get back here?" "It's right here in the database with the all the gate addresses" "Oh OK" in lieu of some less obvious plot driving scenes.